# How would you ask "What makes your mouth water?" in Japanese?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, questions

I want to ask "What makes your mouth water?" in Japanese, but I'm not quite sure what is the right way. I was thinking of saying: あなたは何でよだれが出る？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is not an idiomatic phrase, for instance probably talking to dogs,「あなたは何{なん}でよだれが出{で}る？」might be a decent translation of "What makes your mouth waters?"(probably 「よだれが出{で}ている」 is more appropriate since "what makes you..." induces involuntary movement).

However, when you are asking "What is your the most favorite food?" to your friends, probably the translation could be「思{おも}わずよだれが出{で}る/垂{た}れる食べものは何{なん}ですか？ 」or something like that.

In Japanese, the expression could be used for not only making saliva in your mouth but also it could be used for the symptom which is ravenously collecting something such as a plastic model/manga/video game which is already out of production(It is mostly expressed 「マニア垂涎{すいぜん}の品物{しなもの}」or something.

Comment: Can you say「あの美味しいケーキが垂涎の食べ物です」?

Comment: @ColinStark I think it is bit awkward to use 垂涎{すいぜん} when I am hungry. I'd say 「ケーキが美味しそうで

Comment: Thanks. 

btw, typo:  "water" not "waters"

Answer (score 1):

> あなたは何でよだれが出る

Just from the writing it looks like you wrote なんで (why) but you probably intended "nani de", right? The way you have written it, it looks like you are saying "why does your mouth water".

To formulate your question, I would say "どういうときによだれが出るか" (literally "at what occasions/times does your mouth water"). You could also say "どの場面" or something, or どういう食べ物を見たらよだれが出る".

"Anata" is not a very common word in Japanese, for some reason or another, so you probably can drop that.